# How to test method with an argument inside constructor in order to be able to test other methods inside the component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I would like to test my function with jasmine in angular.

```
 getEmails(text: string): string [] {
        
       

        this.emailAddresses = text.match(this.emailRegExp);
        
        return this.emailAddresses;
    }
```

Unit test

```
it('should get email address from text', () => {
        const text= 'Jon Doe <Jon.Doe@domain.com>'
        const emailAddress= ['jon.doe@domain.com']
        const getEmails= Component['getEmails'](text);
        expect(getEmails).toEqual(emailAddress);

    })
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: _component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.component.getEmails is not a function
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/email.component.spec.ts:49:79)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:358:1)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:124:1)
    at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:561:1)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:576:1)
    at <Jasmine>
```

I don't quite understand whether the way I call the function is wrong or what else can here be the problem?

I am new to Angular testing so please spare with me here.

Thank you all in advance!

---

Update: Error: not a function solved

to be able to call the function, an instance of class should be created:

```
it('should get email address from text', () => {
            const text= 'Jon Doe <Jon.Doe@domain.com>'
            const emailAddress= ['jon.doe@domain.com']
            getEmails= new Component().getEmails(text)
            expect(getEmails).toEqual(emailAddress);
    
        })
```

---

However I am now getting following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at <Jasmine>
    at new Component (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/component.ts:63:51)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/component.spec.ts:61:28)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:358:1)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:124:1)
    at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:561:1)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:576:1)
    at <Jasmine>
```

I think this error appears due to a method call with one argument in the constructor of the class

```
export class ComponentClass(){

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,......){
const service: string = this.Service.get('somename');
}
}
```

I tried to do following in spec file:

```
describe('Component', () => {
    
    let serviceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<Service>;


    beforeEach(async(() => {
        const serviceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service', ['get']);


        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [..],
            imports: [..],
            providers: [{provide: Service, useValue: serviceSpyObj}]
        })
            .compileComponents();
        serviceSpy = TestBed.get(Service);

    }));
```

Comment: Looks like your calling the method statically. You probably want to create an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, getEmails() should be placed in a service, not in the
  component, since it can be reused at different places.
- On the other hand, if you separate your code better following principles (SOLID + clean code) the testing becomes easier.
- On the third hand, your function should do only one thing at a time.
  Currently yours a setter and a getter. It is widely called as
  'bad practice'.

**SPEC.TS:**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from './hello-world.component';

describe('HelloWorldComponent', () => {
  let component: HelloWorldComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HelloWorldComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HelloWorldComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HelloWorldComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should get email address from text', () => {
    const text = `Jon Doe <Jon.Doe@domain.com>`;
    const expectedEmailAddresses = ['Jon.Doe@domain.com'];
    expect(component.getEmails(text)).toEqual(expectedEmailAddresses);
  });
});
```

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
export class HelloWorldComponent {
  private readonly emailRegExp = new RegExp(/(?:[a-z0-9+!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/gi);

  getEmails(text: string): string[] {
    return text.match(this.emailRegExp);
  }
}
```

Please, always use Angular CLI to generate component. Component['getEmails'](text) does not look good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the recommendations. Since I am new to Angular, such recommendations are always valuable. I solved the problem with the described error, it was due calling the function statically like @Get_Off_My_Lawn mentioned. I have now created an instance of the class, but having now another problem due to a method call with an argument inside the constructor. I will  update my question